# How to photograph tire tracks imprinted on a person's clothes?

Tags: photoshop, brushes

I would like to create a photograph where I lie on the flow with a bike next to me and my shirt has some tire tracks as if the bike drove over me.

However, I don't know how to add the tire tracks to my body. I didn't find any online tutorial explaining this.
I hope I can do this with some brushes in Photoshop, but I don't know how to deal with the roughness of the body.

Comment: Smear some ink on the bike tire, then have someone drive it over you.

Comment: After re-reading and editing your question I'm not sure if this question is suitable for Photo.SE as you're asking how to add tire tracks in Photoshop using brushes. This does not involve photography at all so it might be better suited at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always do it the old fashioned way: Put the clothes on a large pillow, drive over them with a wet, dirty tire and then put the clothes on yourself and take a picture. No Photoshop needed.

Comment: Heh, I read the first part of this and thought you were going to suggest that he have someone drive over him with the bike :P

Answer (score 1):

Use compositing. Shoot yourself. Shoot tire tracks. Compose together.

I'd probably start by wetting the tire and rolling it over a clean, dry garage floor. Shoot the track. I'd bracket the exposure so you can select one that pops.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the displacement map feature of Photoshop to be useful. Google/YouTube has more information on what it looks like and how to make it work.